# Trying to display content on side bar based on the visitors location

Tags: ruby-on-rails, geolocation, rubygems, geo, geokit

I am trying to display a list of `salons` that correspond to the users location on the show view of `treatment`.

The two tables don't have a direct relationship.

I have installed the `geokit` gem and now I am trying to work out if I need to add additional columns also to `salon` and `user` to store their respective co-ordinates(lat,lng) so that I can compare them using a scope.

How to I retrieve the users location via their IP and store it?

If someone could show me some example code of what the model/view and controllers should look like it would be of great help.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the location using [geokit-rails](https://github.com/geokit/geokit-rails) gem by following way

```
location = IpGeocoder.geocode('12.215.42.19')
```

The ip is `12.215.42.19`

Also

The `Multi-Geocoder` will also geocode IP addresses and provide failover among multiple IP geocoders. Just pass in an IP address for the parameter instead of a street address. Eg:

```
location = Geocoders::MultiGeocoder.geocode('12.215.42.19')
```

Comment: I have the following in my application controller just to test with `def ip
   @user_location = IpGeocoder.geocode(request.remote_ip)
end` and `It appears you're located in <%= @user_location.city%>.` in my users/index.html.erb file but i am getting an error of `undefined method `city' for nil:NilClass`

Comment: you can use `try` like `<%= @user_location.try(:city)%>`